# Why is event e undefined in callback when firing event manually?

Tags: javascript, mootools, mootools-events

I am using **Mootools** and adding a click event to a link. I have added a function to an event with this:

```
$('addCallRoute').addEvent('click', addCallRoute); // Add button
```

The function contains this:

```
function addCallRoute(e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

The function that fires the event (without an actual click)

```
$('addCallRoute').fireEvent('click');
```

***The Problem:***
When I click on the link physically, `e` is defined. but when I programmatically *fire the event*, `e` is `undefined`. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you're not actually/physically triggering an action but firing it remotely. This is how it works.

`event` normally contains all sort of information about the element from which the action was triggered.

Always check if `event` is defined before trying to use any methods on it. Or do this:

```
link.fireEvent('click', {
    stop: function(){}
});
```

Comment: thank you for your response. I can see that it doesn't *because* it is not physically triggering the event. but programmatically its still firing based on the event-attached element itself. so the question is *why* the argument does not still contain at least *some* event information when its not physically clicked

Comment: The event data is not statically attached, that data will **only** be available if an actual action happens - like a click with a mouse. This is by design.

Comment: that is interesting. can you point me to a resource that talks about this? i haven't been able to find one

Comment: A specific resource no, it's simply the way Events in JavaScript work. Maybe start with MDN, you'll probably find some info regarding to DOM Events there.

Comment: Think about events as an `action` (in this case, the click) followed by a `callback` (the function passed into `addEvent();`). The event information is only available if there is an action, and the callback is completely separate from that. All `fireEvent();` does is run the callback, irrespective of what actions had or hadn't happened.